# How do I get my Maven Integration tests to run

Tags: java, maven-2, testing, surefire

I have a maven2 multi-module project and in each of my child modules I have JUnit tests that are named `Test.java` and `Integration.java` for unit tests and integration tests respectively.  When I execute:

`mvn test`

all of the JUnit tests `*Test.java` within the child modules are executed.   When I execute

`mvn test -Dtest=**/*Integration`

none of the `Integration.java` tests get execute within the child modules.

These seem like the exact same command to me but the one with the **-Dtest=**/*Integration** does not work it displays 0 tests being run at the parent level, which there are not any tests

Comment: Kief's answer should be the accepted one, as it is the current standard for defining integration tests in Maven.

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You can set up Maven's Surefire to run unit tests and integration tests separately.  In the standard unit test phase you run everything that does not pattern match an integration test.  You then **create a second test phase** that runs just the integration tests.

Here is an example:

```xml
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>integration-test</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>test</goal>
          </goals>
          <phase>integration-test</phase>
          <configuration>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>none</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <includes>
              <include>**/*IntegrationTest.java</include>
            </includes>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: I configured this as you said and only the *Test not the *Integration.java files will run when executing:  mvn install

I need to run my *Test.java as the default, but for my nightlty build I need to run both *Test.java and *Integration.java.  I have to execute mvn install  then cd to each sub-child directory and execute mvn -Dtest=**/*Integration test

Comment: You should use the Fail-safe plugin for integration testing, not the sure-fire plugin.  It won't fail the build until _after_ the post-integration phase is complete; allowing you to tear down test resources (a web server, for example) before the build is failed.  Hence, fail-safe.

Comment: for me, as part of pre-integration phase, jetty server starts. Last log line is : [INFO] Started Jetty Server. After that, nothing happens. It gets stuck. maven surefire failsafe plugin doesn't execute tests nor jetty server stops. Any idea what's wrong? I am using same configuration as specified by you.

Comment: This answer is very out of date and should be updated or removed.

Comment: Any help with this one?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48639730/maven-not-running-integration-test-methods

Answer (score 296):

The [Maven build lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) now includes the "integration-test" phase for running integration tests, which are run separately from the unit tests run during the "test" phase. It runs after "package", so if you run "mvn verify", "mvn install", or "mvn deploy", integration tests will be run along the way.

By default, integration-test runs test classes named `**/IT*.java`, `**/*IT.java`, and `**/*ITCase.java`, but this can be configured.

For details on how to wire this all up, see the [Failsafe plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/index.html), the [Failsafe usage page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html) (not correctly linked from the previous page as I write this), and also check out [this Sonatype blog post](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/06/integration-tests-with-maven-part-1-failsafe-plugin/).

Comment: @WillV Correct. The Codehaus' graveyard. And the maven-failsafe-plugin is in Apache now. Sorry. :)

Comment: By default `mvn integration-test` also runs unit tests (using via surefire) but `mvn failsafe:integration-test` runs only the failsafe integration tests.

Comment: Incredibly, the Failsafe plugin documentation, usage page and FAQ do not mention that it runs test classes named **/IT*.java, **/*IT.java, and **/*ITCase.java...

Comment: If it runs after `package` phase, that means I should put all my IT java source code under `src/main/java` instead of `src/test/java` right?

Comment: @HennoVermeulen I was confused about what to name tests as well.  It's described in [Inclusions and Exclusions of Tests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html).  It's nice that the defaults can be overridden, but it'd be nice if they'd mention the defaults earlier on.

Comment: @HennoVermeulen it does, see here https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#test

Comment: @HennoVermeulen and https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes

Comment: @p_champ you are right, I guess I didn't look well enough

Comment: @BruceSun: Neither, put them under `src/it/java`, see also https://khmarbaise.github.io/maui/it-example-1.html

Comment: Without additional configuration in the surefire plugin the IT tests did not run although my IT tests fit the default naming pattern. However calling `mvn clean test-compile failsafe:integration-test` did execute them directly. (Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43470158/9478795)

Answer (score 72):

I have done EXACTLY what you want to do and it works great.  Unit tests "*Tests" always run, and "*IntegrationTests" only run when you do a mvn verify or mvn install.  Here it the snippet from my POM.  serg10 almost had it right....but not quite.

```xml
  <plugin>
    <!-- Separates the unit tests from the integration tests. -->
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
       <!-- Skip the default running of this plug-in (or everything is run twice...see below) -->
       <skip>true</skip>
       <!-- Show 100% of the lines from the stack trace (doesn't work) -->
       <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
       <execution>
          <id>unit-tests</id>
          <phase>test</phase>
          <goals>
             <goal>test</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
                <!-- Never skip running the tests when the test phase is invoked -->
                <skip>false</skip>
             <includes>
                   <!-- Include unit tests within integration-test phase. -->
                <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
             </includes>
             <excludes>
               <!-- Exclude integration tests within (unit) test phase. -->
                <exclude>**/*IntegrationTests.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </configuration>
       </execution>
       <execution>
          <id>integration-tests</id>
          <phase>integration-test</phase>
          <goals>
             <goal>test</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <!-- Never skip running the tests when the integration-test phase is invoked -->
             <skip>false</skip>
             <includes>
               <!-- Include integration tests within integration-test phase. -->
               <include>**/*IntegrationTests.java</include>
             </includes>
          </configuration>
       </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Exactly what I tried to do, but my integration tests kept running during mvn test phase, as I did NOT SKIP THE DEFAULT. I thought configuring the test execution would override it. As you explained, it just adds a new execution (thus everything would run twice). So for me the skip was missing piece. +1 As this configuration answers the question to 100%

Comment: Then feel free to check the box for this response being the answer!

Comment: for me, as part of pre-integration phase, jetty server starts. Last log line is : [INFO] Started Jetty Server. After that, nothing happens. It gets stuck. maven surefire failsafe plugin doesn't execute tests nor jetty server stops. Any idea what's wrong? I am using same configuration as specified by you.

Comment: @Tarun - ask a new question re your issue

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

The associated maven goal is:

`clean compile integration-test -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false`

Comment: Thanks, really nice answer!

Comment: Please add exact version of the plugin where this your solution works, this "alchemy" (I mean running only unit/integration tests in maven) requires it. Thanks

Answer (score 52):

You should use [maven surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) to run unit tests and [maven failsafe plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) to run integration tests.

Please follow below if you wish to toggle the execution of these tests using flags.

#### Maven Configuration

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>${skipUnitTests}</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                </includes>
                <skipTests>${skipIntegrationTests}</skipTests>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <properties>
            <skipTests>false</skipTests>
            <skipUnitTests>${skipTests}</skipUnitTests>
            <skipIntegrationTests>${skipTests}</skipIntegrationTests>
        </properties>
```

So, tests will be skipped or switched according to below flag rules:

Tests can be skipped by below flags:

- `-DskipTests` skips both unit and integration tests
- `-DskipUnitTests` skips unit tests but executes integration tests
- `-DskipIntegrationTests` skips integration tests but executes unit tests

#### Running Tests

Run below to execute *only* Unit Tests

```sh
mvn clean test
```

You can execute below command to run the tests (both unit and integration)

```sh
mvn clean verify
```

In order to run *only* Integration Tests, follow

```sh
mvn failsafe:integration-test
```

Or skip unit tests

```sh
mvn clean install -DskipUnitTests
```

Also, in order to skip integration tests during `mvn install`, follow

```sh
mvn clean install -DskipIntegrationTests
```

You can skip all tests using

```sh
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

Comment: Exactly the solution that I have been searching for may hours. Works fine!, Thankyou Liquidpie.

Comment: UPDATE: the `skipXXTests` trick doesn't work anymore. As of version 3.0.0 of failsafe, the `<skipTests>` option has been removed. Now, we need to use `-DskipITs` to skip integration tests, `-DskipTests` to skip all tests, and `mvn integration-test` to only run its (no unit tests).

Answer (score 36):

You can split them very easily using JUnit categories and Maven.
This is shown very, very briefly below by splitting unit and integration tests.

#### Define A Marker Interface


The first step in grouping a test using categories is to create a marker interface.  
This interface will be used to mark all of the tests that you want to be run as integration tests.

```
public interface IntegrationTest {}
```

#### Mark your test classes

Add the category annotation to the top of your test class.  It takes the name of your new interface.

```
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Category;

@Category(IntegrationTest.class)
public class ExampleIntegrationTest{

    @Test
    public void longRunningServiceTest() throws Exception {
    }

}
```

#### Configure Maven Unit Tests


The beauty of this solution is that nothing really changes for the unit test side of things.
We simply add some configuration to the maven surefire plugin to make it to ignore any integration tests.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.11</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.class</include>
        </includes>
        <excludedGroups>
            com.test.annotation.type.IntegrationTest
        </excludedGroups>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When you do a `mvn clean test`, only your unmarked unit tests will run.

#### Configure Maven Integration Tests


Again the configuration for this is very simple.
We use the standard failsafe plugin and configure it to only run the integration tests.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.class</include>
        </includes>
        <groups>
            com.test.annotation.type.IntegrationTest
        </groups>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The configuration uses a standard execution goal to run the failsafe plugin during the integration-test phase of the build.

You can now do a `mvn clean install`.
This time as well as the unit tests running,  the integration tests are run during the integration-test phase.

Comment: I thought JUnit has no more secrets to me. Good spot!

Comment: This only works if the marker interface already exists somewhere available to Maven. It does not work if your marker interface exists in another module of the same multi-module build.

Comment: @EngineerBetter_DJ what do you mean by that ? You can't do that if you have a multi project based maven config ?

Answer (score 18):

By default, Maven only runs tests that have Test somewhere in the class name.

Rename to IntegrationTest and it'll probably work.

Alternatively you can change the Maven config to include that file but it's probably easier and better just to name your tests SomethingTest.

From [Inclusions and Exclusions of Tests](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html):

> By default, the Surefire Plugin will
> automatically include all test classes
> with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> - `\*\*/Test\*.java` - includes all of its subdirectory and all java
>   filenames that start with "Test".
> - `\*\*/\*Test.java` - includes all of its subdirectory and all java
>   filenames that end with "Test".
> - `\*\*/\*TestCase.java` - includes all of its subdirectory and all java
>   filenames that end with "TestCase".
>
> If the test classes does not go with
> the naming convention, then configure
> Surefire Plugin and specify the tests
> you want to include.

Comment: Hi and thanks
I have two kinds of tests normal POJO Junit tests called SomethingTest.java which get fired.  

I also have integration tests called SomethingIntegration.java which do not get fired.  The SomethingTest.java get fired via mvn test or mvn install.  The second tests do not get fired.  mvn test -Dtest=**/*Integration

Comment: .. and by "Maven only runs tests that have Test somewhere in the class name" you mean "the Maven surefire plugin only runs tests that have Test somewhere in the class name".

Comment: Its not "somewhere in the classname" its "the class name ends with Test", for example MyTest works but MyTests doesn't

Comment: Oh thank god, this was my issue. My class ended in a version numbering and that was not appreciated by maven

Answer (score 18):

You should try using [maven failsafe plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/). You can tell it to include a certain set of tests.

Comment: +1 This is what I use. Works well, and allows you to do pre/post setup, such as starting and shutting down a local servlet container.

Comment: `maven-failsafe-plugin` has gone to [Plugin Graveyard](http://mojo.codehaus.org/plugins.html#Plugin_Graveyard)

Comment: The graveyard page just says the ```failsafe``` plugin has been moved to ```maven-failsafe-plugin```. It looks like the ```maven-failsafe-plugin``` is still active (docs were last pushed March 2014).

Answer (score 11):

Another way of running integration tests with Maven is to make use of the profile feature:

```xml
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>integration-tests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*IntegrationTest.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*StagingIntegrationTest.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
...
```

Running *'mvn clean install'* will run the default build. As specified above integration tests will be ignored. Running *'mvn clean install -P integration-tests'* will include the integration tests (I also ignore my staging integration tests). Furthermore, I have a CI server that runs my integration tests every night and for that I issue the command *'mvn test -P integration-tests'*.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the integration-test phase?  Profiles can then be used for things like integration-testing against various app servers, etc. like Arquillian does.   I'm not a Maven expert, but I think the experts might say this is not very 'Maven-y'.

Comment: @Joshua I guess I do it this way because my integration tests take at least 5 minutes to run and I issue 'mvn clean install' many times a day because I need to update my artifacts in my local maven repo. According to what people are saying above, running 'install' will cause the integration-test phase to run causing me to lose precious developer time.

Comment: Hmm... not sure about 'install' running integration-test.   In any case I'd still use the phase instead of a profile.   Profiles are better off used for things like supporting different app servers, etc.

Comment: I'll go ahead and play around with that then. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @jorge I guess the correct goal to use here would be verify, right?

Comment: What if I use excludedGroups instead of exclude in default one. I tried that but I cannot run the `integration-tests` with that. While I tried `mvn clean install -P integration-tests` it ignores the excluded group and test categorized with `integration-tests` wont run.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the [maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/components/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/skipping-tests.html) to run the unit tests with the build and run the integration tests separately.

```
<project>
    <properties>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    </properties>
    [...]
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipITs>${skipTests}</skipITs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    [...]
</project>
```

This will allow you to run with all integration tests disabled by default. To run them, you use this command:

```
mvn install -DskipTests=false
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't need to do all those setups suggested in other answers and I can run unit tests or integration tests separately.

What I did was:

1. add the config bellow to **pom.xml** in order to instruct maven where are the integration tests files (the java code and the resources files):

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>add-integration-test-source</id>
                <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>src/integration-test/java</source>
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>add-integration-test-resource</id>
                <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/integration-test/resources</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

2. Name the integration test files with the "IT" suffix, like "MyTestIT.java"
3. Execute only the integration tests with this command:

   `mvn failsafe:integration-test failsafe:verify`

In the command above "failsafe:integration-test" will execute the *IT.java files and "failsafe:verify" will tell maven to check if any of the integration tests ran previously have failed. If you don't use 'failsafe:verify' the *mvn* command will exit with success even if one test has failed.

4. To run only the unit tests, run:

   `mvn test`

Comment: Am I really MAD if I find it UNBELIEVABLE when such an ESSENTIAL functionality like this SIMPLE separation of running Unit-tests or Integration-tests still isn't working RELIABLY in Maven ? Do I really want too much ?

Comment: I'm getting following error irrespective which way I configure plugins. Nothing is working for me

maven-failsafe-plugin:3.2.5:integration-test (default-cli) @ <module_name> ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.