# How to execute JSFUnit tests during Maven build

Tags: java, jsf, maven, junit, jsfunit

I would like to execute JSFUnit tests during the Maven build process of the application. How can I configure Maven to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/

This plugin will do the trick.

Example pom:

[How do I get my Maven Integration tests to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399240/how-do-i-get-my-maven-integration-tests-to-run)