# Using the Maven surefire plugin to include tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I am using Maven to build my project.  I currently split testing into different hierarchies:

- Unit tests -> `src/test/java/**/*Test.java`
- Integration tests -> `src/test-integration/java/**/*Test.java`
- External tests -> `src/test-external/java/**/*Test.java`

Here is my `maven-surefire-plugin` section:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>src/test/java/**/*Test.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The `<include>` directive above does not work.  No tests are executed when I run: `mvn clean test`

I tried `**/*Test.java` and it runs all the tests -- unit, integration, and external.  However, for the default test suite, I only want to run the unit tests.

How can I make this work in Maven?

Ref:

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.14.1</version>
```

Answer (score 10):

This is because `<include>` path is relative to `<testSourceDirectory>` which defaults to `${project.build.testSourceDirectory}` = src/test/java. Try this

```xml
<include>**/*Test.java</include>
```

Answer (score 9):

You should separate your unit and integration test cases. Unit tests can be run using Surefire plugin and there is a separate plugin called [Failsafe](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) for running integration tests.

Surefire plugin by default runs all test files whose name ends with `*Test.java`. The trick is to name your integration test files with a different name, say `*IT.java`. Failsafe plugin will identify them as integration tests.

You can find a sample usage in this answer - [How do I get my Maven Integration tests to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399240/how-do-i-get-my-maven-integration-tests-to-run)

Also you dont have to separately configure Surefire plugin if you follow the default setup like putting your test case files in `src/test/java` folder and name your test files as `*Test.java`.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be easier to use an exclusion rather than the inclusion?

```
<excludes>
    <exclude>test-integration/**/*</exclude>
    <exclude>test-external/**/*</exclude>
</excludes>
```

Or something like that?