# Deploying SOA/OSB composites from Jenkins using maven scripts

Tags: oracle, maven, jenkins, soa, sar

I am trying to do a continuous build with Jenkins and trying to deploy those builds using Jenkins.

I have configured Jenkins free style job to check out code from SVN and Invoke top level maven target with `pre-integration-test -P<environment>`.

This job is building and deploying my SOA composites onto weblogic successfully. But I don't want to deploy my every build. I want to restrict my deployments onto the server.

If I configure Jenkins job to build my SOA with `mvn clean package` goal. How I can trigger my other Jenkins job to deploy the previously generated artifacts. We don't have any nexus/artifactory in our infrastructure. We store our builds in our Jenkins workspace.

I have configured two Jenkins jobs, one which builds the application using `mvn clean package` which will trigger other Jenkins job using `mvn pre-integration-test`. But here in my second job, the pre-integration-test is again starting from validating phase producing again my sar. Is there any plugin which deploys my sar without recompiling/rebuilding it again.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Here is my POM:

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
   <groupId>com.oracle.servicebus</groupId>
    <artifactId>sbar-project-common</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.1-1-0</version>
    <relativePath></relativePath>
</parent>

<groupId>ServiceBusApplication1</groupId>
<artifactId>SBProject</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>sbar</packaging>

<description/>
 <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.oracle.servicebus-plugin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>oracle-servicebus-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>12.2.1-1-0</version>
                    <configuration>
                    </configuration>    
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
  </build>

<profiles>  
   <profile>
        <id>Dev</id>
       <properties>
            <oracleServerUrl>http://serverDev.com:7001</oracleServerUrl>
            <oracleUsername>username</oracleUsername>
            <oraclePassword>password</oraclePassword>
            <oracleHome>path to oracle home</oracleHome>
            <customization>path to configuration file</customization>
        </properties>

   </profile>
 </profiles>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your second job build the entire jar again is because you are executing a goal `pre-integration-test` which includes the [maven lifecycle phases](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) prior to it

> `package`  - take the compiled code and package it in its
>   distributable format, such as a JAR.
>
> `pre-integration-test`  - perform
>   actions required before integration tests are executed. This may
>   involve things such as setting up the required environment.

If in case you want to execute the integration tests without building the jar you can configure them to execute in the `test` phase.

> `test` - run tests using a suitable unit testing framework. These tests should not require the code be packaged or deployed.

This can be achieved using `executions` and overriding the phase of integration tests execution. [How do I get my Maven Integration tests to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399240/how-do-i-get-my-maven-integration-tests-to-run)

Comment: Here, why I am using pre-integration-test goal because SOA/OSB deploys through this maven goal. please use this link to understand why I have used pre-integration-test to deploy my artifacts onto weblogic. https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/osb/develop/GUID-F7B8638E-1BE5-44A8-9590-F34E2489625C.htm#GUID-3DFCD3C5-6A28-46AA-9E25-6186D56C47D2

Comment: I don't know how to skip previous phases. I thought maven.package.skip=true may be helpful. But I didn't work out.