# How to make integration tests and unit tests run separately through maven?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

Refer following links    -
[GitHub discussion on how to separate Integration Tests and Unit Tests](https://github.com/krasa/MavenHelper/issues/3#issuecomment-93079564)

As a result, I tried this --

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
          </includes>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/Abstract*.java</exclude>
            <exclude>**/IT*.java</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*IT.java</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*ITCase.java</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <includes>
                <include>**/IT*.java</include>
                <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                <include>**/*ITCase.java</include>
                <include>**/*IntegrationTest.java</include>
              </includes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

---

This is working good to some extent. Meaning, surefire doesn't execute Integration tests and Failsafe doesn't execute unit tests.

But, when I run, `mvn verify` or `mvn integration-test`, the sure-fire plugin is also used.

---

Required Outcome: When run `mvn integration-test`, Unit test shouldn't be run.

---

The below three images are for `mvn verify`

Integration Test:

[image: Integration Test]

[image: Tests Run]

Unit Tests:

[image: Unit Test]

The below image is when I ran `mvn test`

[image: Unit Tests]

Comment: Follow the default naming schema and don't add several includes/excludes  etc. cause the defaults for maven-surefire-plugin and maven-failsafe-plugin are working well...Conventions over configuration is the pardigm...So only configure something if you really need. Otherwise keep the defaults.

Comment: [FailSafe Naming convention](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html). I didn't know this existed until you mentioned.

Comment: @khmarbaise But, does sunfire exclude default of failsafe plugin?

Comment: I recommend a look into the docs like here: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes The exclude is not neccessary...cause maven-surefire and maven-failsafe working via includes instead. See http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maven has a build lifecycle made up out of several phases. When you call a particular one, all phases before that one will be executed first.
See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

There are two ways how you could solve what you want:

- use `-DskipTests` or `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` (https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-skip-maven-unit-test/)
- call the plugin goal directly `mvn clean test-compile failsafe:integration-test`

Answer (score 1):

Both goals `verify` and `integration-test` defined in `maven-failsafe-plugin` runs integration test cases with surefire. Here things are working as expected and as per guideline provided. pls refer this [link](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/plugin-info.html)
for more details:

Comment: This is true. Thanks. But, it doesn't actually solve my core problem.