# Execute Junit tests using Maven

Tags: java, maven, junit

I have 2 classes under src/test/java that I want to run: `scen1.class` and `scen2.class`. Both of these have `@Test` annotated methods.

I have another class called `JunitDefinitions.class` that has only `@Before`, `@After`, `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` methods (no @Test). 
This is also under src/test/java but under a different package.

Assuming I have the default `pom.xml`, what should I add to it in order to be able to execute all these 3 classes?

Comment: Doesn't `mvn install` execute them? What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: You should have junit as dependency with scope`test` in your pom file and usually this should simply run by: `mvn clean test`

Comment: AFAIK the test classes must follow the pattern `*Test.java`. Hence, rename your classes to `Scen1Test` respectively `Scen2Test`. Related: [How do I get my Maven Integration tests to run](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1399240/3429133).

Comment: I have the junit dependency there, where should i add scope test? Currently mvn clean test doesn't run the tests

Comment: Please show the full outline of your project and your pom file please...or put that example project on github so we can take a look at it...

Comment: Here is a link to git: https://github.com/squid12/JunitExample

Comment: BTW, if the nemes of the classes are Test1.class, Test2.class Maven runs them, but it doesn't run the class with the BeforeClass anotation, again, this class doesn't have Test anotation...

Answer (score 1):

- Rename your test classes to Scen1Test.java and Scen2Test.java or include JunitFW.java, Scen1.java and Scen2.java using `<includes>` configuration, as it's described in the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html).
- The class JunitFW only contains a @Before, so it's not detected as a Test. You have to move the @Before to a class containing @Test or include a @Test in JunitFW class and rename it to JunitFWTest to make it work.

By default, the Surefire Plugin will automatically include all test classes with the following wildcard patterns:

```
"**/Test*.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that start with "Test".
"**/*Test.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Test".
"**/*Tests.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Tests".
"**/*TestCase.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "TestCase".
```

Comment: thanks Viniciusartur, but still, Maven doesn't execute JunitFWTest.java... it has only a Before anotation and not Test anotation...

Comment: I tested it and you're right. I updated the answer: The class JunitFW only contains a `@Before`, so it's not detected as a Test. You have to move the `@Before` to a class containing `@Test` or include a `@Test` in JunitFW class and rename it to JunitFWTest to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the renaming of your classes as something like Scen1Test.java and Scen2Test.java as suggested by @viniciusartur, which shall help Maven to recognize the test classes to execute them using surefire-plugin.

Another point to note here is that the reason due to which the `@Before`, `@BeforeClass`, `@After` etc are not executed independently without a [`@Test` method](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html) is that only

> The Test annotation tells JUnit that the public void method to which
>   it is attached *can be run as a test case*. To run the method, JUnit
>   first *constructs a fresh instance of the class* then invokes the
>   annotated method.

From the [documentation of @Before in JUnit](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html)

> Annotating a public void method with @Before causes that method to be
>   run before the Test method. The @Before methods of superclasses will
>   be run before those of the current class.

So inferring as this, while annotations are processed, if there is no @Test annotation present in the class under `/src/test/java`(relative to the question based on maven), no further annotations are meaningful to be processed.

Just to note, if you extend this class with another SubClassTest.java consisting of a `@Test method`, all these methods would be executed then. Since they are processed based on what(`@Test`) to act on to.