# How to run integration test of a spring-boot based application through maven-failsafe-plugin?

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have a spring-boot based application, and the `pom.xml` file is configured as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>exec</classifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/IT*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                        <include>**/*ITCase.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

The `main` method located in class `DemoApplication` as below

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This is a demo application+++++++++++++++++++");
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And my integration test class called `DemoIT` as following.

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.junit.Test;

public class DemoIT {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("This is a integration test.==============");
    }
}
```

Now here is my question, when I issue `mvn clean verify` command, the integration class `DemoIT` is supposed to be executed, and it does. However, my `DemoApplication` isn't running. So I'm wondering if my integration test needs to be executed under the spring-boot application context (the DemoApplication needs running), what should I do to make it happen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since my application is based on **Spring-Boot**, and `spring-boot-maven-plugin` is included in `pom.xml`, so what I need to do is to add following configuration to make sure the lifecycle of our Spring Boot application is well managed around.

```
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>pre-integration-test</id>
    <goals>
      <goal>start</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
  <execution>
    <id>post-integration-test</id>
    <goals>
      <goal>stop</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
</executions>
```

Then when I issue `mvn clean verify`, the spring boot application will be running with our integration test code.

Comment: This happens by default. Right?? Forgive me if I'm wrong.. I am new to this!

Answer (score 10):

[Here is a document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.x/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#integration-tests) for

> Spring Boot Maven Plugin
> Last Published: 2021-01-22|  Version:
> 2.5.x

It says

> While you may start your Spring Boot application very easily from your
> test (or test suite) itself, it may be desirable to handle that in the
> build itself. To make sure that the lifecycle of you Spring Boot
> application is properly managed around your integration tests, you can
> use the start and stop goals as described below:

```xml
<build>
  ...
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>pre-integration-test</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>start</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>post-integration-test</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>stop</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
  ...
</build>
```

For who not familiar with integration test, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1399277) also quite helpful.

Comment: what goals do you invoke in order to kick off your integration tests? 
Does the config that you are talking about start/stop the server only once per a set of ITs?