# Maven multi-module shade one module before using it in another module

Tags: maven-3, maven-shade-plugin, multi-project

I have a multi-module Maven build where one module shades a library, and another module uses the shared library.

If I run `mvn test`, this results in `package com.example.shaded.javax.el7 does not exist`.

If I run `mvn package test`, the compilation and tests pass.

So what I would like is for the shaded module to not just compile but be shaded (packaged) running `maven-shade-plugin:3.2.1:shade` before the dependent module is compiled.

Is it possible to introduce such a target dependency in maven in the pom.xml?

Binding the shade plugin to other phases than package yields this error message:

```
[ERROR] The project main artifact does not exist. This could have the following
[ERROR] reasons:
[ERROR] - You have invoked the goal directly from the command line. This is not
[ERROR]   supported. Please add the goal to the default lifecycle via an
[ERROR]   <execution> element in your POM and use "mvn package" to have it run.
[ERROR] - You have bound the goal to a lifecycle phase before "package". Please
[ERROR]   remove this binding from your POM such that the goal will be run in
[ERROR]   the proper phase.
```

Comment: Why do you mention "gradle" in the last sentence?

Answer (score 1):

**Update** There doesn't seem to be a clean way to do this.

<s>Insert a new Maven module between the two which does the shading. Attach `shade` to the phase `test` in this module. Don't forget to depend on the new module.</s>

The code fails for `mvn test` because this doesn't create any JARs and therefore doesn't invoke the Shade plugin.

You may be tempted to change the phase in which Shade is run to `generate-test-resources` or `test` in the existing module but that could cause other problems if something happens in later phases of the [Maven lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference). That's why I suggest to create a new module where you have no other side effects.

Comment: I edited the question, the solution you suggest seems to be prevented by the shade plugin.

Comment: I think there is something weird going on with "mvn test" because that doesn't create JARs. So I'm wondering what's on the classpath for the next module. Maven probably adds the `target/classes/` folder in this case.

Comment: Can you try to convert the test into an integration test? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399240/how-do-i-get-my-maven-integration-tests-to-run

Comment: Hm... This feels very wrong. It might be possible, but I think the correct answer to my question would be: It is not cleanly possible. So I'd rather do shading differently.